# Hold Arrow Key Down Event with ProcessCmdKey

Tags: c#, events, keyboard, key

I need to perform a certain method as long as an arrow key is being held down. Now, for regular arrow key presses in Visual studio 2012, using `OnKeyDown` did not work, so I needed to use `ProcessCmdKey`, which works like a charm. Is there a way to use `ProcessCmdKey` to detect when an arrow has been released / being held down?

---

I've taken both Markus' and Hans' advice, and combined the two ideas. I used the `ProcessKeyPreview` method, but I am still having some issues. When I hold down any arrow key, this method will not detect that `WM_KEYDOWN` has happened... but as soon as I release my finger from the key, it actually DOES notice that `WM_KEYUP` has happened.

The interesting this is that when I hold down any other key (i.e. letter 'S'), it properly recognizes when it has been pressed and released. I've posted a fragment of my code below:

```
const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

    protected override bool ProcessKeyPreview(ref Message m)
            {
                int msgVal = m.WParam.ToInt32();            
                if (m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)
                {
                    switch ((Keys)msgVal) {
                        case Keys.Down:
                            Console.WriteLine("down pressed"); //not detected
                            break;
                        case Keys.S:
                            Console.WriteLine("S pressed!"); //detected
                            break;
                    }
                }
                if (m.Msg == WM_KEYUP)
                {
                    switch ((Keys)msgVal)
                    {
                        case Keys.Down:
                            Console.WriteLine("down released"); //detected
                            break;
                        case Keys.S:
                            Console.WriteLine("s released!"); //detected
                            break;
                    }
                }
                return base.ProcessKeyPreview(ref m);
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot see the KeyUp event with ProcessCmdKey(), it was made to only handle KeyDown events.  You'll need to tackle this at a much lower level if the form contains controls.  The trick is to intercept the message before Winforms sends it through the normal key-handling and WndProc chain.  That requires implementing the IMessageFilter interface.  Like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter {  // NOTE: added IMessageFilter
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
    }
    protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e) {
        Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
        base.OnFormClosed(e);
    }

    bool IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage(ref Message m) {
        // Trap WM_KEYUP/DOWN for Keys.Down key
        if ((m.Msg == 0x100 || m.Msg == 0x101) && (Keys)m.WParam.ToInt32() == Keys.Down) {
            bool repeat = (m.LParam.ToInt32() & (1 << 30)) != 0;
            bool down = m.Msg == 0x100;
            // But only for this form
            Form form = null;
            var ctl = Control.FromHandle(m.HWnd);
            if (ctl != null) form = ctl.FindForm();
            if (form == this) {
                OnCursorDown(down, repeat & down);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    private void OnCursorDown(bool pressed, bool repeat) {
        // etc..
    }
}
```

Comment: No, not for the navigation keys, it is a VB6 compat property.  Nor does it fire KeyDown, same reason ProcessCmdKey doesn't.

Comment: Ok, I tested the code that I posted above and it fires WM_KEYDOWN when I press arrow down and WM_KEYUP when I let go of it. I've got a form with a button and a text box. The focus is on the button. Pardon my ignorance...what I am missing? (I'll withdraw my answer if you can tell me why it works for me.)

Comment: I like your answer...I just don't understand why my example works for me and you're saying it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can overload ProcessKeyPreview instead, which will let you see the WM_KEYDOWN message as well as the WM_KEYUP message. Be sure to turn on KeyPreview for the form.

```
WM_KEYDOWN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx

WM_KEYUP:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646281(v=vs.85).aspx
```

Example:

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
    public TestForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyPreview = true;
    }

    const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

    protected override bool ProcessKeyPreview(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_KEYDOWN:
                Console.WriteLine(m.LParam);
                break;

            case WM_KEYUP:
                Console.WriteLine(m.LParam);
                break;
        }
        return base.ProcessKeyPreview(ref m);
    }
}
```

Comment: He already tried OnKeyDown(), this won't work either for the same reason.

Comment: @HansPassant I must be misreading the question, because I tested my example and it shows me the key down events, repeats, and the final key up event.

Comment: Put a button on the form to reproduce the OP's problem.